# mapping memory data ptr to qt input field

Tags: c++, qt, memory, data-binding, mapping

how can I "link" a memory data ptr to a qt input field ?

data view is dynamically refreshed, if memory has changed.
memory data is overwritten if input has been done.

I had this function in fox gui toolkit (FXDataTarget class). 
I would need the same/similar  thing in qt.

Comment: Can you share some code of what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it is the best solution, but a possible approach would be as follows:

- Inherit a `Qobject` as a wrapper around your pointer.
- Implement the valueChanged and setValue signal and slots and let them accept Qstrings.
- Implement a member `detectChange()` that detects changes (if the array isn't too big store a full copy of the array to check againts). If a change is detected, let it raise the `ValueChanged` signal)
- Set `QTimer` to call `detectChange()` periodically.
- Connect The `valueChanged` signal of your object to the `setValue` slot of your text box and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

finally, the code looks like this example, here coded only for an int * ptr.

```
class Updater : public QObject
    {
      Q_OBJECT
public:
    Updater(int *);
    QTimer *timer;
    int myData_mem;
    int *mydata;
public slots:
    void setText(const QString &value);
    void detectChange();
signals:
    void hasChanged(const QString &value);
 };


Updater::Updater(int *mydata_) : QObject()
{
 timer = new QTimer(this);
 connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(detectChange()));
 timer->start(500);
 mydata = mydata_;
 myData_mem = mydata_;
}

void Updater::detectChange()
{
    if (*mydata != myData_mem)
    {
    myData_mem = *mydata;
    emit hasChanged(QString::number(myData_mem));
   }
}

void Updater::setText(const QString &value)
{
myData_mem = value.toInt();
*mydata = myData_mem;
}

int shared_data;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
// your main qt code goes here

// ....

// and updater setup ,now :
QLineEdit *editor = new QLineEdit("0");

Updater updater(&shared_data);

QObject::connect(editor, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),
                     &updater, SLOT(setText(const QString &)));

QObject::connect(&updater, SIGNAL(hasChanged(const QString &)),
                 editor, SLOT(setText(const QString &)));
// ....
}
```